# how to set the exact height of an element in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

please help fix the code:

```
import Tkinter as tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("340x470") 

row5 = tkinter.Frame(root)
row5.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')
label5 = tkinter.Label(row5, text = 'Audio', width = 10, anchor='e')
label5.pack(side = 'left')
entry5 = tkinter.Text(row5, height = '4')
entry5.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'x', expand = 'yes')       

row6 = tkinter.Frame(root, borderwidth = 10, height = 20, bg = 'red')
row6.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')
button = tkinter.Button(row6, text = 'Send', height = 20, width = 20, relief = 'raised', cursor = 'hand1', font = ('times', 14, 'bold'))

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

the problem is that I have asked for "row6" height of 20, and the screen height is much greater than 20

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is not obvious what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: the problem is that the red area is explicitly specified height 20 px. and the red area in the picture has a greater height
http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/vvv.png

Comment: That's because your button has height specified as 20 **pt**, not px. Refer to the documentation.

Comment: @BartoszKP: you are incorrect. The height does not represent points, it represents the number of lines of text.

Comment: @BryanOakley You're right, thanks. The point remains the same though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'height' value in the button measures lines of text, not pixels. So you have requested a box tall enough to draw 20 lines of text. Try reducing it to 1 or 2:

```
button = tkinter.Button(row6, text = 'Send', height = 2, width = 20, relief = 'raised', cursor = 'hand1', font = ('times', 14, 'bold'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things working against you. First, when you specify the height of a button, if that button has text then the height attribute refers to lines of text. Thus, a height of 20 in your button requests a button 20 lines tall.

Second, is that the default behavior of a container widget (typically Frames, but actually any widget) is to "shrink to fit" or "expand to fit" everything it contains. So, even if you set the height of a frame to 20 pixels, it will actually be just big enough to contain all of its children. This is a Good Thing, and what you want 99.9% of the time. You should avoid trying to make fixed-size windows, and instead let tkinter decide the appropriate dimensions for you.

This feature of expanding or contracting is called "geometry propagation". You can turn this behavior off when you do need precise control of the size of a container widget. There are several examples on this website for how to do that. But again, it's rarely ever needed.